# Good estimator of $p$ knowing $\operatorname{Bin}(2,p)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

We consider the statistical sample ${1,0,2,1,1,0,1,0,0}$ and we assume that the values of this sample come from a binomial distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(2, p)$.

How can we estimate the value of $p$?

For me, an intuitive estimator is $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. So $\hat{p}$ should be just $\frac{2}{3}$. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are binominal $(2,p)$, and $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ then $Y$ is binomial $(2n,p)$.

Since $E[Y]=2np$ and you observed $Y=6$ in your sample, the maximum likelihood estimator will arise from solving $$2n\hat p=6$$

The solution is $\hat p=\frac{6}{18}$, or $\frac{1}{3}$.

As for the proposed answer of $2/3$, just look at your sample. Most of the numbers are closer to $0$ than $2$ right?

---

Another way to approach is that if you take the estimators for each of your individual sample points, you will get $\frac{1}{2}, 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 0, 0$ (just dividing by two). The average of these numbers is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Why can you say $E(Y) = Y = 6$?

Comment: @David The expected value of $Y$ is $2np$. We set this equal to 6 (the sample) in order to solve for the maximum likelihood estimator of $p$.

Comment: It is not that clear for me. Can you precise in details why is that true in your answer

Comment: I would just be interested in why $E(Y) = Y = 6$. If you can just prove that formally, I would be very happy.

Comment: $E[Y]$ is not $6$, it is $2np$. Setting that equal to $6$ (the sample) and solving for $p$ is how we find the estimator. If you just think about your sample as taken from $\text{Binomial}(18,p)$ then it should be clear why sampling $6$ yields an estimate of $6/18$.

Answer (score 0):

Your "intuitive estimator" is an unbiased estimator of the mean of a random variable.  But the mean of $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ is $np$, and you want $p$.

Comment: So $2/3 = np = 9p \implies p =  2/27$, right?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used $n$ because that's already in use in the problem.  I should have written the mean of $\text{Bin}(k,p)$ is $kp$. In your case $k=2$.

Comment: So, I guess the answer is good, right?